# what does the barebone mean in computer field?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I see a video which introduce the node.js. during the introduction, Ryan Dahl say javascript is a very bare bones language at 36:12.
what does this mean?

Comment: The term [bare bones](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bare-bones?q=bare+bones) has no computing specific meaning.

Comment: There is no meaning in computer field.

Comment: so what does this mean anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the linked definition indicates, "bare bones" means "simple, elementary, no-frills."  Think of a skeleton, rather than a filled-out body with all its organs.  "Bare bones" is a general expression, with no meaning specific to the computing field.

Comment: By the way, I would dispute the statement that JavaScript is bare bones, but that's another conversation.